# How to cut a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I reduce that table in Oracle's SQL:

```
PersonNr   TestID    Date          resultTestA    resultTestB
Person1     1        01.01.19        pos
Person1     1        01.01.19                       neg
Person1     2        02.02.19        pos
Person2     3        02.02.19        neg           
Person2     4        02.02.19        neg
```

The result must be:

```
PersonNr   TestID    Date          resultTestA    resultTestB
Person1     1        01.01.19        pos             neg             
Person1     2        02.02.19        pos
Person2     3        02.02.19        neg             
Person2     4        02.02.19        neg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use aggregation

```
PersonNr,TestID,Date,max(resultTestA),max(resultTestB)
from table group by PersonNr,TestID,Date
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's work! I have already tried it, but it turned out that in the columnt Date was a Time too. Now I have trunced it and it works.